# Linked Lists & quickSort

Tags: java, list

I was trying another approach to sort a linked list. Aside from the available methods, i decided to take each node from the linked list and place it in an array and by that i would be able to compare the data variables easily. I applied the quickSort on the array and this is what i got...however, when the result is displayed, I'm getting the memory address of the nodes and not the Students information

This is what is appearing: (as an output)

Sorted list is:

```
homework2.Node@44b471fe
homework2.Node@22a7fdef
homework2.Node@431067af
homework2.Node@6a07348e
null
```

This is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();

Student s = new Student(1, "John", 20, "Italy", "2011");
list.addStudent(s);
Student s2 = new Student(2, "Mark", 19, "UAE", "2010");
list.addStudent(s2);
Student s3 = new Student(3, "Sally", 35, "UAE", "2000");
list.addStudent(s3);

 System.out.println("Students in the list: ");
list.print();

 Node[] n = list.convertA(list);
  quickSort(n, 0, (n.length-1));
  System.out.println("Sorted list is:");

  for(int q =0;q<n.length;q++){
      System.out.println(n[q] + " ");
  }
}

public static int partition(Node arr[], int left, int right) {

int i = left, j = right;

Node tmp;

Node pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

while (i <= j) {

    while (arr[i].getStudent().getAge() < pivot.getStudent().getAge()) {
        i++;
    }

    while (arr[j].getStudent().getAge() > pivot.getStudent().getAge()) {
        j--;
    }

    if (i <= j) {

        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;

    }

}
return i;

}

public static void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right) {

int index = partition(arr, left, right-1);

if (left < index - 1) {
    quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
}

if (index < right) {
    quickSort(arr, index, right);
}
}
```

the Node class is as follows:

```
public class Node {

private Student student;
public Node link;

public Node() {
    student = null;
    link = null;
}

public Node(Student s) {
    student = s;
}

public Node(Student s, Node l) {
    student = s;
    link = l;
}

public Object getData() {
    return student.toString();
}

public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setLink(Node link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.student.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> .however, when the result is displayed, I'm getting the memory address
>   of the nodes and not the Students information

Because you didn't override the `toString` method in your `Node` class so you print the default behavior of this method defined in the `Object` class :

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

First, you have to override the `toString` method in your `Student` class :

```
@Override
public String toString (){
  return this.id+"-"+this.name+"-"+this.age+"-"+this.country+"-"+this.year;
}
```

Then you can override the toString method in your Node class :

```
 @Override
 public String toString (){
   return this.student.toString();
 }
```

And then let your for loop like this.

Or just override the `toString` method in the Student class :

And modify your for loop like this :

```
for(int q =0;q<n.length;q++){
      System.out.println(n[q].getStudent() + " ");
}
```

Comment: now it's giving me the exception" String cant be casted to a node

Comment: @PeterLawrey this means i should change the array's type to a String but I need the new type to contain the Student's  data members so that I can sort the age

Comment: @ZouZou The tostring method is already overriden in my student class

Comment: @P.성미 May could you show your Node class ? Does each node contains a Student ?

Comment: @ZouZou yea I forgot about the toString in the node class, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @P.성미 `System.out.println(n[q].getStudent() + " ");` should work too.

Comment: @ZouZou just added the node class

Comment: @P.성미 Did you just add the `toString` method ? Does it works now ?

Comment: @ZouZOu yea I just added the toString method in the Node class, but the problemis with the type of my array.. I'm working with an array of Nodes because i want to access the students ages..but that doesnt seem to work right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40368/discussion-between-zouzou-and-p-)

Comment: @P.성미 . you should have a Node is the array and not try to cast a String to a Node.  You can parse the String and create a Node based on the information parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue and sorted the array,

there was an issue in my quickSort method.. for the index 
it should be:

```
int index = partition(arr,left,right)
```

instead of :

```
int index = partition(arr, left, right-1);
```

As ZouZou pointed out earlier, for loop was faulty  so I fixed that as well

Thanks a lot for the help !